# Compute $\Bbb E [(n-S_n)^+]$ where $S_n$ is a sum of i.i.d Poisson random variables.

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. Poisson random variables with $\lambda = 1$, i.e. $\Bbb P\{X_i=k\}=\frac{e^{-1}}{k!}$. Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, and surely $S_n$ is a Poisson with parameter $n$. Compute the expectation $\Bbb E [(n-S_n)^+]$, where ${(n - {S_n})^ + } = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{n - {S_n}}&{{S_n} \le n}\\
0&{{S_n} > n}
\end{array}} \right.$.

Anyone can provide some help how to compute this expectation? Thank you!

Comment: $$=e^{-n}\sum_{k\le n}\frac {n^k}{k!}(n-k)=e^{-n}\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!}\sim \sqrt{\frac n {2\pi}}$$